# Sync files from Windows to Freebox(Linux) : prevent file recopy

Tags: bash, synchronization, rsync, xcopy, robocopy

I try to sync files from my Windows 7 computer to my Freebox (running Linux
I used `rsync` from unix like terminal (MobaXterm) and `xcopy` directly from windows bash as well.

In both case, whatever the set of option I used (inclusing operations on file attributes), I am unable to sync properly.

Problem is that each file is considered as new at each sync, and hence copied again, even if unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

Problem comes from the file system. Windows is usually NTFS while Freebox (and some Linux) is FAT32 (in general not NTFS). File comparison based on dates concludes on differences between files. Using `robocopy` command on window with special option `/fft` solves the issue.

Example:

```
robocopy src dest /fft /e /purge
```

Will copy all files recursively from `src` to `dest`, removing on `dest` the non existing ones on `src` and handling correctly the files date attributes through different file systems, avoiding unecessary recopy.